# Add multiple vector sources in vector layer

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer

I want to add multiple vector source to single vector layer. For adding single vector source to vector layer I am using below code and its working perfectly fine:

```
const vectorSource1 = new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSON(),
      url: 'http://localhost:8085/geoserver/test/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=test%3Aebs&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson'
      
    });
    const vectorlayer1 = new VectorLayer({
      source: vectorSource1,
      style: new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
          width: 2,
        }),
      }),
    });
```

Though documentation clearly states that a single source can be added.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html

But is there a way to add multiple vectorSource1,vectorSourc2, vectorSource3 and so on to vectorlayer1 or do I have to add multiple vectorlayer2, vectorlayer3, vectorlayer4 and so on correpondingly for each vector source?

Answer (score 7):

You can have a single source, fetch and parse from multiple data urls and add the features to the same source.  You will need to specify the data and view projections.

```
const format = new GeoJSON();
const vectorSource = new VectorSource();
const vectorlayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
});

function loadFromUrl (url) {
  fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    response.json().then(function (result) {
      vectorSouce.addFeatures(
        format.readFeatures(result, {
          dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
          featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        })
      }
    });
}

loadFromUrl('http://localhost:8085/....');
loadFromUrl('http://localhost:8085/....');
```